# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string when trying to enter time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert this record to this table but actually it doesn't work and I'm totally confused

```
INSERT INTO Attendance_Records 
VALUES ('12/12/2017', '1:00:00AM', '2:00:00AM', 'x y')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Attendance_Records] 
(
    [date] DATE NOT NULL,
    [staff] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    [start_time] TIME(7) NULL,
    [end_time] TIME(7) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([date] ASC, [staff] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([staff]) 
          REFERENCES [dbo].[Staff_Members] ([username]) 
          ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: because you are forgetting the STAFF column. You have to insert them in the correct order, or specify the order on the insert

Comment: You should **always** define **what columns** you're inserting into! Make it a (good) habit !  `INSERT INTO dbo.Attendance_Records ([date], start_time, end_time, staff) VALUES (......)`

Comment: And while you're at it - try to use **more meaningful** and expressive column names - `[date]` is *not* a very good column name, and it and collides with the [T-SQL reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) - try to avoid this - always

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments-- it's because you are forgetting the STAFF column. You have to insert them in the correct order, or specify the order on the insert

```
INSERT INTO Attendance_Records ([date],[start_time],[end_time],[staff])
VALUES ('12/12/2017', '1:00:00AM', '2:00:00AM', 'x y')
```

or...

```
INSERT INTO Attendance_Records 
VALUES ('12/12/2017','x y', '1:00:00AM', '2:00:00AM')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your column order messed up in your insert? You're trying to insert the value 'x y' into a TIME column is going to give you an error.

Edit it to this perhaps:

```
INSERT INTO Attendance_Records
VALUES ('12/12/2017', 'x y', '1:00:00AM', '2:00:00AM')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not specifying the column names in your insert so it's applying them in DB order.  'x y' is being assigned to end_time.